# Is there a Scale Controls in google map SDK for iOS ?

Tags: ios, google-maps, controls, scale

I want to use Scale controls in the google map for iOS,but I found nothing  in the document of google map SDK for iOS  about scale controls.Is there a Scale Controls in google map SDK for  iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use zoom levels in GMSCameraPosition by providing lang, lat values.

[GMSCameraPosition Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_position#ab36cfa7ca6930755c4bf9e1393d052ba)

> - (float) zoom [read, assign]
>     Zoom level.
>     Zoom uses an exponentional scale, where zoom 0 represents the entire world as a 256 x 256 square. Each successive zoom level increases magnification by a factor of 2. At zoom 10, the entire world is a 256k x 256k square, and so on.

For the controls you need to use your custom controls -,+ and for zoom in and out.
Use any of the Static Public Member Functions for adjusting the zoom levels on the GMSCameraPosition.
 
    Then  `[mapView_ setCamera:myCamera];`

[zoom level of the camera, read this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#zoom)

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
float actualZoom;
#define SENSITY_OF_ZOOM 0.5
```

set your actualZoom after you alloc init your map:

```
actualZoom = _mapView.camera.zoom;
```

the method:

```
 - (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position{
        if (fabsf(_mapView.camera.zoom - actualZoom) > SENSITY_OF_ZOOM) {
            NSLog(@"user zoomed enough");
            if (_mapView.camera.zoom > actualZoom) {
               actualZoom = actualZoom + SENSITY_OF_ZOOM;
            }
            else{
                actualZoom = actualZoom - SENSITY_OF_ZOOM;
            }
        }
    }
```