# Is there any option in google map sdk to display the scale bar option in the bottom of google map in IOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps

Is there any option in google map sdk to display the scale bar option in the bottom of google map in IOS? The sample project given from the google itself is not displaying the mas scaling. Do we need to set YES or NO to any API using google mp sdk to display the map scaling for iOS? Screen shot attached[image]

Answer (score 1):

I known it is an old question but if you or someone else is looking for a GMSMapView with a graphical scale there is an implementation at [CHGMapView](https://github.com/grethi/CHGMapView).

As i know the GoogleMaps SDK will currently not offer a graphical scale like they do in the GoogleMapsAPP.

Comment: @BhargavRao , which is the duplicate question? Maybe it was deleted?

Comment: @Efren yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762182/is-there-a-scale-controls-in-google-map-sdk-for-ios/44226539#44226539. Deleted my comment here

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure in google map sdk, but apple mapkit provides span so we can calculate using its delegate method. If you can do the same using google map sdk, it should work.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

      MKCoordinateSpan mapSpan = mapView.region.span;

      NSString * mapScaleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" 1 = ~110 km -> %f = ~ %f km", mapSpan.latitudeDelta, mapSpan.latitudeDelta*110];

      self.mapScaleLabel.text = mapScaleString;
```

`}`